# Google Scripts - Error When Calling Function in Another Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm posting the entirety of the code I have below.

I'm working in Google Scripts, pulling some data from a sheet that is constantly changing, performing calculations and then repopulating the sheet.

The data is being called into an app, so I'm trying to do the calculations as quickly as possible (so if anyone can tell me more efficient ways to do this that would be helpful too).

When I try to call the `invoicePrice()` function or the `tiers()` function I get a TypeError: function cannot be found.

```
function invoicePrice() {
      // define row to do calculations on
      var AVals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange("A1:A1000").getValues();
      var ALast = AVals.filter(String).length;

      // Set order No. here

      var orderNoPrev = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast - 1, 3).getValue();
      var orderNo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 3).setValue(orderNoPrev + 1);
      var total = 0;

      // invoicePrice the total number of items
      var itemRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 4, 1, 14).getValues()[0];

      // set the values of the constants on the Products page

      var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Products").getRange("F1:F1000").getValues();
      var pLast = priceRange.filter(String).length;
      var pGrab = priceRange.splice(0,pLast);

      var invoicePrice = 0;

      // set weight of case values

      var weightRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Products").getRange("V1:V1000").getValues();
      var wLast = weightRange.filter(String).length;
      var wGrab = weightRange.splice(0,wLast);


      for (var i = 0, len = 13; i <= len; i++) {
          // SUBTOTAL THE ORDER AMOUNT
          var orderAmount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, i + 4).getValue();

          total += orderAmount;

          // SET/KG PRICES
          var perKGInvoice = pGrab[i + 1].map(Number);

          // SET WEIGHTS
          var weights = wGrab[i + 1].map(Number);

          // SET CASE PRICE
          var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;

          // SUM OF PRODUCT PRICE * ORDER AMOUNT * WEIGHT OF CASE
          invoicePrice += orderAmount * perKGInvoice * weights;


      }
    Logger.log(invoicePrice, ALast, pGrab, wGrab);
    return [invoicePrice, ALast, pGrab, wGrab];



  }

  function tiers() {
      var invoicePriceCall = invoicePrice();
      var invoicePrice = invoicePriceCall[0];
      var ALast = invoicePriceCall[1];

      var beefDiscount = 0;
      var sfDiscount = 0;
      var currentTier = ""

      // Set the invoice order value required ($ amount)

      var tier1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(3, 3).getValue();
      var tier2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(4, 3).getValue();
      var tier3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(5, 3).getValue();
      var tier4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(6, 3).getValue();
      var tier5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(7, 3).getValue();
      var minNotmet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(10, 3).getValue();

      // Set the discount tier levels for beef (% discount)
      var tier1BeefDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(3, 4).getValue();
      var tier2BeefDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(4, 4).getValue();
      var tier3BeefDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(5, 4).getValue();
      var tier4BeefDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(6, 4).getValue();
      var tier5BeefDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(7, 4).getValue();

      var tier1SfDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(3, 5).getValue();
      var tier2SfDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(4, 5).getValue();
      var tier3SfDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(5, 5).getValue();
      var tier4SfDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(6, 5).getValue();
      var tier5SfDiscount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscountGrid").getRange(7, 5).getValue();




      if (invoicePrice < tier1) {
          beefDiscount = tier1BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier1SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Minimum Not Met"
      }
      else if (invoicePrice < tier2) {
          beefDiscount = tier1BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier1SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Tier 1"
      }
      else if (invoicePrice < tier3) {
          beefDiscount = tier2BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier2SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Tier 2"
      }
      else if (invoicePrice < tier4) {
          beefDiscount = tier3BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier3SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Tier 3";
      }
      else if (invoicePrice < tier5) {
          beefDiscount = tier4BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier4SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Tier 4";
      }
      else {
          beefDiscount = tier5BeefDiscount;
          sfDiscount = tier5SfDiscount;
          currentTier = "Tier 5";
      }


      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 20).setValue(beefDiscount);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 21).setValue(sfDiscount);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 22).setValue(currentTier);

      return [beefDiscount, sfDiscount, tier1];

  }


  function calcsOnColumns2() {

      // call price range and weight from previous function 
      var invoicePriceCall = invoicePrice();
      var invoicePrice = invoicePriceCall[0];
      var ALast = invoicePriceCall[1];
      var priceRange = invoicePriceCall[2];
      var weightRange = invoicePriceCall[3];

      // call tiers function
      var tiers = tiers();
      var beefDiscount = tiers[0];
      var sfDiscount = tiers[1];
      var tier1 = tiers[2];

      // set sums to 0

      var beefSum = 0;
      var sfSum = 0

      for (var i = 0, len = 13; i <= len; i++) {
          // SUBTOTAL THE ORDER AMOUNT
          var orderAmount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, i + 4).getValue();

          // SET/KG PRICES
          var perKGInvoice = priceRange[i + 1].map(Number);

          // SET WEIGHTS
          var weights = weightRange[i + 1].map(Number);

          // SET CASE PRICE
          var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;

          // Split up seafood and beef with if statement:

          if (i < 9) {
              // set discount case price
              var discountCaseBeef = perKGInvoice - (perKGInvoice * beefDiscount);
              // set the total price of the discounted cases in the order (ie, order price * discount)
              var beefCaseOrder = discountCaseBeef * orderAmount * weights;
              beefSum += beefCaseOrder;
              // Nice and Formatted sheet
              var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;

              if (orderAmount) { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, i + 32).setValue(orderAmount + " cases @" + discountCaseBeef.toFixed(2) + "/kg = ~$" + beefCaseOrder.toFixed(2)); }

          }

          else {
              var discountCaseSF = perKGInvoice - (perKGInvoice * sfDiscount);
              // set the total price of the discounted cases in the order (ie, order price * discount)
              var sfCaseOrder = discountCaseSF * orderAmount * weights;
              sfSum += sfCaseOrder;
              // Nice and Formatted sheet
              var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;
              if (orderAmount) { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, i + 32).setValue(orderAmount + " cases @" + discountCaseSF.toFixed(2) + "/kg = ~$" + sfCaseOrder.toFixed(2)); }

          }



          if (i == len) {
              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 24).setValue(beefSum);
              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 25).setValue(sfSum);
              // if statement to go here if min order size not met

              var sumOfSums = beefSum + sfSum;
              // swap out 75 with referenced value
              if (sumOfSums > tier1) { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 27).setValue(sumOfSums) }
              // swap out phrase with changable phrase
              else { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 27).setValue("Minimum order size not met") }

              var totalDiscount = invoicePrice - sumOfSums

              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 29).setValue(totalDiscount);
              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay").getRange(ALast, 30).setValue(invoicePrice);


          }



      }


  }
```

Comment: Is `TypeError: function cannot be found.` the exact error message you get? Is your script bound to a spreadsheet or alone standing?

Comment: `TypeError: invoicePrice is not a function (line 136, file "Copy of Code")` is the exact error I get when trying to run calcsOnColumns2().

It is bound to a spreadsheet. The only reason its bound is because prior to this I'd never used Google Scripts and don't know best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

A correctly declared function (`invoicePrice`), when called from another function (`calcsOnColumns2`) is `undefined`.

**Steps to reproduce**

Imagine you have three functions named `A`,`B`,`C`, then calling `B` causes your error:

```
function A() {
  var A = 0;
  return [A];
}

function C() {
  var a = A();
  var A = a[0];
}

function B() {
  A();
  C();
}
```

You probably noticed that this is what your functions boil down to - the behaviour is due to *hoisting*:

1. function `B` calls `A`, which returns an `Array` with first element `0`;
2. [never happens] function `C` calls function `A` and overrides `A` to output of `A`;

Instead, on step two `A` is declared to be equal to first element of `a` and only then `A` is called. Since `a` gets its value from call to `A`, `A` will be `undefined` and, as a result: `[undefined]()` -> "is not a function"

**Optimization**

1. Stay DRY (don't repeat yourself) - when you see code that looks the same or has the same structure, consider making it reusable (making it a function, class, object, a variable - it depends). It makes your code readable and easier to debug, but a lot of the time it saves you extra calls to APIs, recalcs and thus time (especially if you repeat I/O).
2. Don't use comments unless strictly necessary (reduces readability a lot - crucial if you need others to help debug your code or doing it yourself [may sound counter-intuitive, but you'll be surprized]).
3. Don't put I/O (`getRange()`,`getValue()`) in loops unless having no choice - input / output is always slow, so it is usually better to load everything into memory and work on data there.
4. Keep consistent scope: if you declare a variable, every accessor should be either in the same scope or nested (e.g. don't declare two vars of the same name inside `if...else`, move it to outer scope).
5. Use TypeScript or at least [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/index.html) - will keep you from going insane while trying to understand why your function expected one type and received another (just as in your case) [UPD: I've also added JSDOC comments to solution].

I've applied a few optimizations to your script, take a look (please, check before using, since we don't have sample data, I couldn't test it). There is a lot more you can do (especially regarding the loop in `calcsOnColumns2`), but that should be a start:

```js
/**
 * [Your decription here]
 * @returns {Number[]}
 */
function invoicePrice() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var subtotalDisplaySheet = ss.getSheetByName('SubtotalDisplay');

    // define row to do calculations on
    var AVals = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange("A1:A1000").getValues();
    var ALast = AVals.filter(String).length;

    // Set order No. here
    var orderNoPrev = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast - 1, 3).getValue();
    var orderNo = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 3).setValue(orderNoPrev + 1);

    // invoicePrice the total number of items
    var itemRange = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 4, 1, 14).getValues()[0];

    // set the values of the constants on the Products page
    var productsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Products");

    var priceRange = productsSheet.getRange("F1:F1000").getValues();
    var pLast = priceRange.filter(String).length;
    var pGrab = priceRange.splice(0, pLast);

    var outputInvoicePrice = 0;

    var weightRange = productsSheet.getRange("V1:V1000").getValues();
    var wLast = weightRange.filter(String).length;
    var wGrab = weightRange.splice(0, wLast);

    var orderAmounts = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(Alast, 17).getValues();

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = 13; i <= len; i++) {
        var nextI = i + 1;

        var orderAmount = orderAmounts[0][i + 4];

        total += orderAmount;

        var perKGInvoice = pGrab[nextI].map(Number);
        var weights = wGrab[nextI].map(Number);

        var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;

        outputInvoicePrice += orderAmount * casePrice;
    }

    Logger.log(outputInvoicePrice, ALast, pGrab, wGrab);
    return [outputInvoicePrice, ALast, pGrab, wGrab];
}

/**
 * Gets values from 5 rows in 
 * a column starting from row 3
 * @param {Sheet} sheet 
 * @param {Number} column 
 * @returns {*[]}
 */
function getGridValues(sheet, column) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(3, column, 5, 1);
    return range
        .getValues()
        .map(function (row) {
            return row[0];
        });
}

/**
 * [Your decription here]
 * @returns {Number[]}
 */
function tiers() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var discountGridSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DiscountGrid");

    var invoicePriceCall = invoicePrice();
    var outputInvoicePrice = invoicePriceCall[0];
    var ALast = invoicePriceCall[1];

    var beefDiscount = 0;
    var sfDiscount = 0;
    var currentTier = "";

    var tierValues = getGridValues(discountGridSheet, 3);
    var tier1 = tierValues[0];
    var tier2 = tierValues[1];
    var tier3 = tierValues[2];
    var tier4 = tierValues[3];
    var tier5 = tierValues[4];

    var minNotmet = discountGridSheet.getRange(10, 3).getValue();

    var tierBeefDiscountValues = getGridValues(discountGridSheet, 4);
    var tier1BeefDiscount = tierBeefDiscountValues[0];
    var tier2BeefDiscount = tierBeefDiscountValues[1];
    var tier3BeefDiscount = tierBeefDiscountValues[2];
    var tier4BeefDiscount = tierBeefDiscountValues[3];
    var tier5BeefDiscount = tierBeefDiscountValues[4];

    var tierSfDiscountValues = getGridValues(discountGridSheet, 5);
    var tier1SfDiscount = tierSfDiscountValues[0];
    var tier2SfDiscount = tierSfDiscountValues[1];
    var tier3SfDiscount = tierSfDiscountValues[2];
    var tier4SfDiscount = tierSfDiscountValues[3];
    var tier5SfDiscount = tierSfDiscountValues[4];

    if (outputInvoicePrice < tier1) {
        beefDiscount = tier1BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier1SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Minimum Not Met";
    }
    else if (outputInvoicePrice < tier2) {
        beefDiscount = tier1BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier1SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Tier 1";
    }
    else if (outputInvoicePrice < tier3) {
        beefDiscount = tier2BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier2SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Tier 2";
    }
    else if (outputInvoicePrice < tier4) {
        beefDiscount = tier3BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier3SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Tier 3";
    }
    else if (outputInvoicePrice < tier5) {
        beefDiscount = tier4BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier4SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Tier 4";
    }
    else {
        beefDiscount = tier5BeefDiscount;
        sfDiscount = tier5SfDiscount;
        currentTier = "Tier 5";
    }

    var subtotalDisplaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay");
    var subtotalDisplayRange = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 20, 3, 1);
    subtotalDisplayRange.setValues([
        [beefDiscount],
        [sfDiscount],
        [currentTier]
    ]);

    return [beefDiscount, sfDiscount, tier1];
}

/**
 * Foramts amount string
 * @param {Number} amount 
 * @returns {Function}
 */
function formatAmount(amount) {
    return function (discount, caseOrder) {
        return amount + " cases @" + discount.toFixed(2) + "/kg = ~$" + caseOrder.toFixed(2);
    };
}

/**
 * Counts sum by discount, amount and weights
 * @param {Number} amount 
 * @param {Number} weights 
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function countSum(amount, weights) {
    return function (discount) {
        return discount * amount * weights;
    };
}

/**
 * Counts discount case per Kg
 * @param {Number} perKG 
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function countDiscountCase(perKG) {
    return function (discount) {
        return perKG - (perKG * discount);
    };
}

/**
 * [Your decription here]
 */
function calcsOnColumns2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var subtotalDisplaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("SubtotalDisplay");

    var invoicePriceCall = invoicePrice();
    var outputInvoicePrice = invoicePriceCall[0];
    var ALast = invoicePriceCall[1];
    var priceRange = invoicePriceCall[2];
    var weightRange = invoicePriceCall[3];

    var tiers = tiers();
    var beefDiscount = tiers[0];
    var sfDiscount = tiers[1];
    var tier1 = tiers[2];

    var beefSum = 0;
    var sfSum = 0;

    var orderAmounts = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 17).getValues();

    for (var i = 0, len = 13; i <= len; i++) {
        var orderAmount = orderAmounts[0][i + 4];

        var nextI = i + 1;

        var perKGInvoice = priceRange[nextI].map(Number);
        var weights = weightRange[nextI].map(Number);

        var casePrice = perKGInvoice * weights;

        var subtotalRange = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, i + 32);

        var formatAmountOrder = formatAmount(orderAmount);
        var countDisountSum = countSum(orderAmount, weights);
        var countPerKGCase = countDiscountCase(perKGInvoice);

        // Split up seafood and beef with if statement:
        if (i < 9) {
            var discountCaseBeef = countPerKGCase(beefDiscount);
            var beefCaseOrder = countDisountSum(discountCaseBeef);
            beefSum += beefCaseOrder;
        } else {
            var discountCaseSF = countPerKGCase(sfDiscount);
            var sfCaseOrder = countDisountSum(discountCaseSF);
            sfSum += sfCaseOrder;
        }

        if (orderAmount) {
            subtotalRange.setValue(
                i < 9 ?
                    formatAmountOrder(discountCaseBeef, beefCaseOrder) :
                    formatAmountOrder(discountCaseSF, sfCaseOrder)
            );
        }

        if (i == len) {
            subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 24).setValue(beefSum);
            subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 25).setValue(sfSum);
            // if statement to go here if min order size not met

            var subtotalRange = subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 27);

            var sumOfSums = beefSum + sfSum;

            subtotalRange.setValue(sumOfSums > tier1 ? "Minimum order size not met" : sumOfSums);

            var totalDiscount = outputInvoicePrice - sumOfSums;

            subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 29).setValue(totalDiscount);
            subtotalDisplaySheet.getRange(ALast, 30).setValue(outputInvoicePrice);
        }
    }

}
```

**Notes**

1. Although modern JavaScript will help you avoid the issue, you should
   never override any variable names unless you know exactly why you
   are doing that (`i++` is an example, however functional style will
   say that even this is problematic).
2. Never truncate error messages / code when posting on SO for the sake of readability -knowing what exactly happened is invaluable for us to help you (`invoicePrice` is `undefined` says so much more).

**References**

1. [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in JavaScript